# Keplerian orbits as conic sections

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion

It is usually mentioned in textbooks that keplerian orbits are conic sections.

However, no further discussion is given on applications of this geometrical fact.

So does this cone have any significance on its own? Does it play any role in perturbation theory, in few-body problems or anywhere else?

Comment: The cone itself alone haven't any significance. What I know is [2-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem) shows every mass' orbit relative to its nearest greater mass is a conic section. Determining the orbit around the other masses is another story which is more difficult and even sometimes impossible and "Perturbation theory" is built to solve these kind of orbits numerically.

Comment: I think it's more just a 'neat fact', and perhaps can help visualizing different types of orbits and their relations to one another.

Comment: *"does this cone have any significance"* Hmmm ... there is a "this cone". There is a whole (infinite) family of cones. Nor is the relationship between the cones and the set of {ellipses (including circles), parabola, and hyperbolas} really necessary in the context of gravitation. They were studied that way be the ancient Greeks and it provides a useful way to understand the mathematical connection between the different figures, but they are not the only way to develop these shapes.

Answer (score -1):

**Not an answer**

I think you are asking a great question. Don't be discouraged, this might be investigating further.

Look into [Pole-Polar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar) relations as a conic section defines a 1-to-1 mapping between points and lines on the plane. There are special points defined on orbits (focal points) and there might be a significance to the directrix line of the conic in terms related to the motion or momentum of the planet.

Comment: Why did you post "not an answer" *as an answer*? Either you think this is an answer and you don't need the disclaimer, or you shouldn't have typed this into the box labeled "your answer".

Comment: Because it is merely a hint. I did not answer the question on the geometry of orbits.